# Failed opening required

Tags: filesystem

I am new in wordpress development. Tried include a selfwritten php-file into **htdocs/wp-content/plugins/abc/abc.php**

IDE sugesting me to use: `require_once  '../WPNonce/WPNonce.php';`
[image: IDE Suggestion of file path]

but WordPress contradicts when opening in webbrowser:

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../WPNonce/WPNonce.php'`

How could i include this php-file (its a class inside)?

Comment: Is the file you want to include part of your plugin?

Comment: Later i want to be able to use it in all plugins. right now it is in the plugin folder. https://imgur.com/tif3vOv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress includes many [functions for determining paths and URLs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Available_Functions) to files or directories within plugins, themes, and WordPress itself.

```
 $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ); // wp-content/plugins/
 require_once($plugin_dir.'WPNonce/WPNonce.php');
```

While using `plugin_dir_path()`, keep in mind that **the “plugin” part of the name is misleading** – it can be used for any file, and **will not return the directory of a plugin unless you call it within a file in the plugin’s base directory.**

or alternatively, you can also use WordPress constant `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`

```
 require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/WPNonce/WPNonce.php');
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have now selected this directory `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/WPNonce.php');` I hope that's a good style(?). and by the way. Surprisingly, PhpStorm finds the file directly by using Strg+B (compare to the parent question) as i normaly expecting.

Comment: If you put your self-written file  `WPNonce.php` in `wp-includes` folder, it will deleted on WordPress update, so  `wp-content` folder is preferred for all code customization.